# Modify plot style in a tkz-fct-plot for a whole tikzpicture at once

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

Is it possible to modifiy the plot style (for example color) for every plot in a tikzpicture environment at once?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,every plot/.style={color=green,thick}]
\tkzInit[xmax=10,ymax=10]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid
\tkzFct[domain=0:10]{\x}
\tkzFct[domain=0:10]{\x**2}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a scope

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=10,ymax=10]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid
\begin{scope}[color=red,thick]
    \tkzFct[domain=0:10]{\x}
    \tkzFct[domain=0:10]{\x**2}     
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pgfplots is a more powerful tool than my package and I'm sure you can find something more consistent with pgfplots to define the style of the plots